# Mostrar dato en un TextView y cambiarlo cada vez que seleccione otro dato de un Spinner

Tags: java, android

Quiero mostrar los datos en el txtloc, pero este siempre muestra el primer dato del spinner y no cambia cuando selecciono otro dato del spinner. Por otro lado el txtpro si cambia cuando selecciono otro dato dentro de su spinner... Cómo podría hacer que ambos spinner guarden sus datos en un TextView y cambien cada vez que seleccione otro dato dentro de sus spinner?

Este es mi código

```
 txtpro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpro);
    txtloc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtloc);

    spinnerPro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerProvincia);
    spinnerLoc = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLocalizacion);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.array_provincias,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerPro.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerPro.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    int[] localidades = {R.array.array_sevilla, R.array.array_malaga};

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            localidades[i],
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLoc.setAdapter(adapter);

    txtloc.setText(spinnerLoc.getSelectedItem().toString());
    txtpro.setText(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());

}
```

Y estos array tengo en mi archivo String.xml

```
  <string-array name="array_provincias">
        <item>Sevilla</item>
        <item>Malaga</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_sevilla">
        <item>Tomares</item>
        <item>Camas</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="array_malaga">
        <item>Casares</item>
        <item>Estepona</item>
    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OnItemSelectedListener()` en su Actividad:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // Tu código aquí

   String selecteditem = spinner.getselecteditem().tostring();
   textview.settext(selecteditem);


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // Tu código aquí
    }

});
```

O de esta menara:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {

   String selecteditem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
   textview.setText(selecteditem);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {        
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, acabo de ver el código y me sirvió.